# Cocoa - NSWindow animation when displayed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nswindow

How would I add some sort of CoreAnimation effect when showing a simple nswindow?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what kind of animation you want?

Comment: A 'flip' animation is somewhat of an animation I would prefer so that its not so sudden to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done an animation like you describe before. However, it wasn't an easy task. Since your animation extends outside the bounds of the window itself, you'll need to render the animation in an oversized, transparent window. When the animation completes, you can order in the real window and remove the transparent one.

You'll need an image of the window to use as the content of your animation, so what I would do is order the window in (and probably make it the key window, too, so that it looks focused), but put it well off-screen so the user doesn't see it. Then use [`CGWindowListCreateImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) to grab a screenshot of the window. Now you'll have what you need to create an animation.

After the animation completes, just order the real window over top of the transparent one, then remove the transparent window. Getting the math right so that the image of the window in the animation and the real window is a bit tricky, but it's definitely doable.

Comment: How did you put it "well off-screen"? I have tried using setFrame to do that, but a small portion of the window is still always on-screen. I.e. the frameworks don't allow me to move the window completely off-screen.

Comment: Never mind, subclassing NSWindow and returning the unaltered frame from the constrainFrameRect:toScreen: method did the trick! Thanks!