# NSWindow zooming "into view" (first tiny, then zooms to normal size)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

Does anyone here happen to know how to accomplish this effect from Espresso.app?

http://f.cl.ly/items/1j1V1q322f2K202v2T2s/ScreenFlow.mov

Notice how the title bar also starts off tiny.

Do you happen to have any code on hand? Or some general idea of how it would be best to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another post which contained my answer: [Cocoa - NSWindow animation when displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926521/cocoa-nswindow-animation-when-displayed)

See also my comment there. That was also crucial for making this work properly.

Comment: It would be useful if you posted some of your code to demonstrate the solution.